# How to disable autofill styles (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css

I've a address form as shown in the screenshot
[image: screenshot]

I'm using google chrome, and when it autofills all the info, The style of it changes to this for every input box as shown in the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I don't want these styles overlay. How can I fix this?

I couldn't think of anytime to try. I tried adding `!important` in front of the background color style, which didn't work

Edit:
To Fix it:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active{
/* The color here can't be transparent, so made it same as background color */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #604AC8 inset !important; 
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;

}
```

Comment: @LS_ Yes, I don't use stackoverflow frequently. What should I do next

Comment: Don't worry! That's an auto generated comment because I flagged the question as duplicate. Try with the solution in the linked answer, if you can't get it working add an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your html / css code and I'll take a look.